# Cesium Sandcastle file not loading in browserin version 1.15

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I have uploaded my Cesium 1.15 code to server and I am loading the SandCastle files in browser like this: http://example.com/gen/Cesium-1.15_new/Apps/Sandcastle/gallery/Box.html

but I am getting following long error after showing "Loading..." for about 40seconds.

Not able to solve this. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: DataSources/RectangleGraphics,DataSources/StaticOutlineGeometryBatch,DataSources/WallGeometryUpdater,DataSources/WallGraphics,Renderer/AutomaticUniforms,Renderer/Buffer,Renderer/BufferUsage,Renderer/ClearCommand,Renderer/ComputeCommand,Renderer/ComputeEngine,Renderer/Context,Renderer/ContextLimits,Renderer/createUniform,Renderer/createUniformArray,Renderer/CubeMap,Renderer/CubeMapFace,Renderer/DrawCommand,Renderer/Framebuffer,Renderer/loadCubeMap,Renderer/MipmapHint,Renderer/PassState,Renderer/PickFramebuffer,Renderer/PixelDatatype,Renderer/Renderbuffer,Renderer/RenderbufferFormat,Renderer/RenderState,Renderer/Sampler,Renderer/ShaderCache,Renderer/ShaderProgram,Renderer/ShaderSource,Renderer/Texture,Renderer/TextureMagnificationFilter,Renderer/TextureMinificationFilter,Renderer/TextureWrap,Renderer/UniformState,Renderer/VertexArray,Renderer/VertexArrayFacade,Renderer/WebGLConstants,Scene/Appearance,Scene/ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider,Scene/Billboard,Scene/BillboardCollection,Scene/BingMapsImageryProvider,Scene/BingMapsStyle,Scene/BlendEquation,Scene/BlendFunction,Scene/BlendingState,Scene/Camera,Scene/CameraEventAggregator,Scene/CameraEventType,Scene/CameraFlightPath,Scene/createTangentSpaceDebugPrimitive,Scene/CreditDisplay,Scene/CullFace,Scene/CullingVolume,Scene/DebugAppearance,Scene/DebugModelMatrixPrimitive,Scene/DepthFunction,Scene/DepthPlane,Scene/DiscardMissingTileImagePolicy,Scene/EllipsoidPrimitive,Scene/EllipsoidSurfaceAppearance,Scene/FrameRateMonitor,Scene/FrameState,Scene/FrustumCommands,Scene/FXAA,Scene/GetFeatureInfoFormat,Scene/getModelAccessor,Scene/Globe,Scene/GlobeDepth,Scene/GlobeSurfaceShaderSet,Scene/GlobeSurfaceTile,Scene/GlobeSurfaceTileProvider,Scene/GoogleEarthImageryProvider,Scene/GridImageryProvider,Scene/GroundPrimitive,Scene/HeightReference,Scene/HorizontalOrigin,Scene/Imagery,Scene/ImageryLayer,Scene/ImageryLayerCollection,Scene/ImageryLayerFeatureInfo,Scene/ImageryProvider,Scene/ImageryState,Scene/Label,Scene/LabelCollection,Scene/LabelStyle,Scene/MapboxImageryProvider,Scene/Material,Scene/MaterialAppearance,Scene/Model,Scene/ModelAnimation,Scene/ModelAnimationCache,Scene/ModelAnimationCollection,Scene/ModelAnimationLoop,Scene/ModelAnimationState,Scene/ModelMaterial,Scene/modelMaterialsCommon,Scene/ModelMesh,Scene/ModelNode,Scene/Moon,Scene/NeverTileDiscardPolicy,Scene/OIT,Scene/OpenStreetMapImageryProvider,Scene/OrthographicFrustum,Scene/Pass,Scene/PerformanceDisplay,Scene/PerInstanceColorAppearance,Scene/PerspectiveFrustum,Scene/PerspectiveOffCenterFrustum,Scene/PickDepth,Scene/PointPrimitive,Scene/PointPrimitiveCollection,Scene/Polygon,Scene/Polyline,Scene/PolylineCollection,Scene/PolylineColorAppearance,Scene/PolylineMaterialAppearance,Scene/Primitive,Scene/PrimitiveCollection,Scene/PrimitivePipeline,Scene/PrimitiveState,Scene/QuadtreeOccluders,Scene/QuadtreePrimitive,Scene/QuadtreeTile,Scene/QuadtreeTileLoadState,Scene/QuadtreeTileProvider,Scene/RectanglePrimitive,Scene/Scene,Scene/SceneMode,Scene/SceneTransforms,Scene/SceneTransitioner,Scene/ScreenSpaceCameraController,Scene/SingleTileImageryProvider,Scene/SkyAtmosphere,Scene/SkyBox,Scene/StencilFunction,Scene/StencilOperation,Scene/Sun,Scene/SunPostProcess,Scene/terrainAttributeLocations,Scene/TerrainState,Scene/TextureAtlas,Scene/TileCoordinatesImageryProvider,Scene/TileDiscardPolicy,Scene/TileImagery,Scene/TileMapServiceImageryProvider,Scene/TileReplacementQueue,Scene/TileState,Scene/TileTerrain,Scene/TweenCollection,Scene/UrlTemplateImageryProvider,Scene/VerticalOrigin,Scene/ViewportQuad,Scene/WebMapServiceImageryProvider,Scene/WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider,Shaders/AdjustTranslucentFS,Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/AllMaterialAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/BasicMaterialAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/EllipsoidSurfaceAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/EllipsoidSurfaceAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceColorAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/PerInstanceFlatColorAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/PolylineColorAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/PolylineMaterialAppearanceVS,Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceFS,Shaders/Appearances/TexturedMaterialAppearanceVS,Shaders/BillboardCollectionFS,Shaders/BillboardCollectionVS,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/degreesPerRadian,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/depthRange,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon1,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon2,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon3,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon4,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon5,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon6,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/epsilon7,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/infinity,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/oneOverPi,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/oneOverTwoPi,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/pi,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/piOverFour,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/piOverSix,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/piOverThree,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/piOverTwo,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/radiansPerDegree,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/sceneMode2D,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/sceneMode3D,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/sceneModeColumbusView,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/sceneModeMorphing,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/solarRadius,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/threePiOver2,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/twoPi,Shaders/Builtin/Constants/webMercatorMaxLatitude,Shaders/Builtin/CzmBuiltins,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/alphaWeight,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/antialias,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/columbusViewMorph,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/computePosition,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/cosineAndSine,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/decompressTextureCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/eastNorthUpToEyeCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/ellipsoidContainsPoint,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/ellipsoidNew,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/ellipsoidWgs84TextureCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/equalsEpsilon,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/eyeOffset,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/eyeToWindowCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/geodeticSurfaceNormal,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/getDefaultMaterial,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/getLambertDiffuse,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/getSpecular,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/getWaterNoise,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/getWgs84EllipsoidEC,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/hue,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/isEmpty,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/isFull,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/latitudeToWebMercatorFraction,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/luminance,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/metersPerPixel,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/modelToWindowCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/multiplyWithColorBalance,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/nearFarScalar,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/octDecode,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/packDepth,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/phong,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/pointAlongRay,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/rayEllipsoidIntersectionInterval,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/RGBToXYZ,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/saturation,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/signNotZero,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/tangentToEyeSpaceMatrix,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/translateRelativeToEye,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/translucentPhong,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/transpose,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/unpackDepth,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/windowToEyeCoordinates,Shaders/Builtin/Functions/XYZToRGB,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/depthRangeStruct,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/ellipsoid,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/material,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/materialInput,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/ray,Shaders/Builtin/Structs/raySegment,Shaders/CompositeOITFS,Shaders/DepthPlaneFS,Shaders/DepthPlaneVS,Shaders/EllipsoidFS,Shaders/EllipsoidVS,Shaders/GlobeFS,Shaders/GlobeFSPole,Shaders/GlobeVS,Shaders/GlobeVSPole,Shaders/Materials/BumpMapMaterial,Shaders/Materials/CheckerboardMaterial,Shaders/Materials/DotMaterial,Shaders/Materials/FadeMaterial,Shaders/Materials/GridMaterial,Shaders/Materials/NormalMapMaterial,Shaders/Materials/PolylineArrowMaterial,Shaders/Materials/PolylineGlowMaterial,Shaders/Materials/PolylineOutlineMaterial,Shaders/Materials/RimLightingMaterial,Shaders/Materials/StripeMaterial,Shaders/Materials/Water,Shaders/PointPrimitiveCollectionFS,Shaders/PointPrimitiveCollectionVS,Shaders/PolylineCommon,Shaders/PolylineFS,Shaders/PolylineVS,Shaders/PostProcessFilters/AdditiveBlend,Shaders/PostProcessFilters/BrightPass,Shaders/PostProcessFilters/FXAA,Shaders/PostProcessFilters/GaussianBlur1D,Shaders/PostProcessFilters/PassThrough,Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorFS,Shaders/ReprojectWebMercatorVS,Shaders/ShadowVolumeFS,Shaders/ShadowVolumeVS,Shaders/SkyAtmosphereFS,Shaders/SkyAtmosphereVS,Shaders/SkyBoxFS,Shaders/SkyBoxVS,Shaders/SunFS,Shaders/SunTextureFS,Shaders/SunVS,Shaders/ViewportQuadFS,Shaders/ViewportQuadVS,ThirdParty/Autolinker,ThirdParty/gltfDefaults,ThirdParty/knockout-3.2.0,ThirdParty/knockout-es5,ThirdParty/knockout,ThirdParty/measureText,ThirdParty/mersenne-twister,ThirdParty/sprintf,ThirdParty/topojson,ThirdParty/Tween,ThirdParty/Uri,ThirdParty/when,ThirdParty/zip,Widgets/Animation/Animation,Widgets/Animation/AnimationViewModel,Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/BaseLayerPicker,Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/BaseLayerPickerViewModel,Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/createDefaultImageryProviderViewModels,Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/createDefaultTerrainProviderViewModels,Widgets/BaseLayerPicker/ProviderViewModel,Widgets/CesiumInspector/CesiumInspector,Widgets/CesiumInspector/CesiumInspectorViewModel,Widgets/CesiumWidget/CesiumWidget,Widgets/ClockViewModel,Widgets/Command,Widgets/createCommand,Widgets/FullscreenButton/FullscreenButton,Widgets/FullscreenButton/FullscreenButtonViewModel,Widgets/Geocoder/Geocoder,Widgets/Geocoder/GeocoderViewModel,Widgets/getElement,Widgets/HomeButton/HomeButton,Widgets/HomeButton/HomeButtonViewModel,Widgets/InfoBox/InfoBox,Widgets/InfoBox/InfoBoxViewModel,Widgets/NavigationHelpButton/NavigationHelpButton,Widgets/NavigationHelpButton/NavigationHelpButtonViewModel,Widgets/PerformanceWatchdog/PerformanceWatchdog,Widgets/PerformanceWatchdog/PerformanceWatchdogViewModel,Widgets/SceneModePicker/SceneModePicker,Widgets/SceneModePicker/SceneModePickerViewModel,Widgets/SelectionIndicator/SelectionIndicator,Widgets/SelectionIndicator/SelectionIndicatorViewModel,Widgets/subscribeAndEvaluate,Widgets/SvgPathBindingHandler,Widgets/Timeline/Timeline,Widgets/Timeline/TimelineHighlightRange,Widgets/Timeline/TimelineTrack,Widgets/ToggleButtonViewModel,Widgets/Viewer/Viewer,Widgets/Viewer/viewerCesiumInspectorMixin,Widgets/Viewer/viewerDragDropMixin,Widgets/Viewer/viewerPerformanceWatchdogMixin,Workers/createTaskProcessorWorker
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeoutmakeError @ require.js:165checkLoaded @ require.js:693(anonymous function) @ require.js:714
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Sandcastle on GitHub pages, you need to disable jekyll by adding  a .nojekyll file to the root directory of your pages repository or gh-pages branch. See [our blog post](https://cesiumjs.org/2015/10/07/Hosting-Cesium-Sandcastle-with-GitHub-pages/) for the details.